# Castle components dispose order

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

We have a number of castle windsor components declared in a config file.
Some of the components somewhere deep inside might require the services of other components.

The problem is when the application is being closed and the Container is being disposed. During Dispose()/Stop() of the Startable/Disposable component (A) when it requires the services of some other component (B) ComponentNotFoundException then raised. By that time B is already removed from the container.

I've noticed that the order of components declarations in app config file is important. And reodering A and B solves the problem.

Is there a better way to influence the order in which the components are disposed?

**Edited:**
Following a request in comments I provide here a sample code that will throw ComponentNotFoundException:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IoC.Resolve<ICriticalService>().DoStuff();
        IoC.Resolve<IEmailService>().SendEmail("Blah");
        IoC.Clear();
    }
}

internal class CriticalService : ICriticalService, IStartable
{
    public void Start()
    {}

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Should throw ComponentNotFoundException, as EmailService is already disposed and removed from the container
        IoC.Resolve<IEmailService>().SendEmail("Stopping");
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {}
}

internal class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public void SendEmail(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EmailService Disposed.");
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

internal interface ICriticalService
{
    void DoStuff();
}

internal interface IEmailService : IDisposable
{
    void SendEmail(string message);
}

public static class IoC
{
    private static readonly IWindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());

    static IoC()
    {
        _container.AddFacility<StartableFacility>();
        // Swapping the following 2 lines resolves the problem
        _container.AddComponent<ICriticalService, CriticalService>();
        _container.AddComponent<IEmailService, EmailService>();
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return (T)_container[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

Note: See a comment in the code how swapping the order of inserting components in the container solves the problem.

Comment: Start/Stop are two concerns, provided by the StartableFacility, and Disposable is another concern, unrelated in principle to start/stop. The StartableFacility ensures that the Stop concern is the first one executed when "decommissioning" a component. If you're saying that Dispose() is executed before Stop() then it looks like a bug. Can you show us some code, maybe post a testcase?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems to me that when the Container is disposed, it iterates through each startable component and calls on each Stop(), then Dispose() and removes it from the Container. While I would expect it first should call Stop() on all startables and then dispose them and remove from the Container.

Comment: Yes, the container iterates through each startable component and calls on each Stop(), then Dispose(), that's the behavior. Can you post a testcase that throws ComponentNotFoundException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By having a static IoC class you're actually using the container as a service locator, thus losing most of the benefits of dependency injection.

The problem is that without a proper injection, Windsor doesn't know about the CriticalService - IEmailService dependency, so it can't ensure the proper order of disposal.

If you refactor to make this dependency explicit, Windsor disposes the components in the correct order:

```
internal class CriticalService : ICriticalService, IStartable
{
    private readonly IEmailService email;

    public CriticalService(IEmailService email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
 ...
}
```

[Here's how it would look](http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/WindsorInitConfig/WindsorInitConfig/StartStopDisposeTests2.cs?spec=svn283&r=283) like after refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I completely agree with your comments about constructor dependency. However, bear in mind that it was just a sample, our system is much bigger and more complicated. It's not easy to achieve, but we will try to refactor this area. As for StartableFacility, I just forgot to add it to the sample code (left it in config file). Please see the updated sample code. It doesn't work with startable facility.

Comment: Tested with 2.1.1 and StartableFacility - ComponentNotFoundException

Comment: By the way, what's your opinion on this pattern by Ayende:
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/07/30/IoCAndFluentInterfaces.aspx

Comment: Boris, about the post by Ayende - it is a bad thing to do. We now have a much better tools than ServiceLocator, namely TypedFactoryFacility, DynamicParameters, UsingFactoryMethod... strive to **not** to have to call to the container in your code, outside of single well defined place in your inftastructure (like controller factory)

Comment: @Boris: can you copy&paste and try my code? Can you send me a .zip with the exact code and DLLs you're using?

Comment: @Mauricio: I tried your code. It works fine. I've sent you my sample project to your gmail account. Thanks!

Comment: @Krzysztof: Thanks a lot for the info. We developed our framework about 2 years ago, based on Ayende's blog posts about Castle and RhinoMocks. Maybe it's about time to review it...

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, feel that any system that requires `Dispose()` to be called in a specific order has a flaw in the design.

`Dispose()` should **always** be safe to call.  The errors should only occur if a component is used after disposal, and then `ObjectDisposedException` makes the most sense.  In a case like this, I would rework your components so that they don't use other componetry during their `Dispose()` method (it really should be about cleaning each component's own, private resources).  This would eliminate this issue entirely.

Comment: On one hand you are right, and I should probably iterate through all Startable components and call Stop() on them in the order I like, and then call Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer.Dispose(). On the other hand, I would expect the Castle framework to do it on my behalf as they provide Dispose() method.

Comment: "One of unique features of Windsor is that it manages the lifecycle of objects it creates for you. What this means (among other things) is that it will dispose all disposable objects it instantiates."

Comment: That really has nothing to do with it, though.  They'll call Dispose on your components, but your components should not rely on other components to exist once Dispose() has been called.  The order in which disposal occurs shouldn't matter...